# How can I share a session across multiple subdomains that sharing the same web forms application in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I have an web form application where, in the course of using the application, a user might click from

```
en.mydomain.com
```

to

```
us.mydomain.com
```

what's a good way to share session info across multiple subdomains without using SQL SERVER?

I have already tried to include in the web.config the following line:

```
<httpCookies domain=".mydomain.com"/>
```

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You need to use a shared server to host session.

Comment: both subdomains are in the same server.